# SQL - Proper way to create unique pairs of foreign keys

Tags: sql, database-design

Suppose we have this "matchmaking" logic, where we want to store the matches between users. I created this schema for the table and wanted to be sure if this is the correct way to store that information.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    a INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (a < b) REFERENCES users (id),
    b INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (a < b) REFERENCES users (id),
    frequency INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS matches_a_b_uidx ON matches (a, b);
```

I want to make sure that there are no duplicates of matches, so if a=1 and b=2, we cannot have a=2 and b=1, as they are the same. Also, no matches with themselves.

Is this duplicate `CHECK (a < b)` the correct way to structure this kind of logic?

Comment: A two-column constraint can't be given as a column constraint. Do it as _one_ table constraint instead,

Comment: a and b are poor column names. Consider user1 and user2, or something even better, instead.

Comment: @jarlh Yeah thanks for the tip! But this is really just a mock example, as I'm not actually matching users per se. Also, are you talking about doing a standalone `CHECK (a < b)` after the columns declarations? Would this be for you the real proper way then?

Comment: Yes, one single _table constraint_, after the columns declarations.

Comment: Awesome, I totally forgot about table constraints. Also I was wondering if there was another completely different way to design that schema that would be more practical, but perhaps this is already that one. Do you want to leave an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the two column constraints, have one table constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    a INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
    b INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
    frequency INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CHECK (a < b)
);
```